# Why is Twitter quota for app-auth greater for some endpoints and less for others, compared to user-auth?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, quota

Twitter allows developers to use [app-auth](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only.html) rather than user-auth, but sometimes the API quotas for app-auth are *better* than with user-auth, and sometimes they're **worse** - why is that?

From https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits.html :

[image]

In the table above you can see that if you want to [search tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html), it's better to use app-auth, but if you want to simply do [bulk lookup by id](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-lookup), it's better to use user-auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Twitter API policy and rate-limit question rather than a general programming question appropriate for Stack Overflow so I expect that others may tag this to be closed.

Here's the thing: app-only auth is really intended as a stop-gap or fill-in measure. What I mean by this is, imagine you have 10 users that are all signed in to your app and you are using their tokens to access the API; what if one of these users is super popular and you need a *few* more calls. You can then use the application-level app-only auth to make a few additional search requests (for example) to "top up" what might run out of requests per user. If you have 10 users that are *all* super popular, you might use all of the app-level requests to backfill for them quite fast.

Basically you're asking Stack Overflow how Twitter's developer policy and choices work, and this is probably not the best forum for such a conversation. Twitter's developer forums are at twittercommunity.com. Enjoy!

Comment: Many thanks - I've reposted this to https://twittercommunity.com/t/why-is-twitter-quota-for-app-auth-greater-for-some-endpoints-and-less-for-others-compared-to-user-auth/122744?u=rtyley but I appreciate your perspective on the intended purpose of app-auth as a stop-gap measure, which I think was missing from https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only.html